# Why does this JSON parse fail in the specified location in Rust?

Tags: json, rust, serde

The following Rust program works fine using `cargo run` on cargo 1.39.0-nightly:

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
use serde_json::Value as JsonValue;

#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize)]
struct JData
{
    names: Vec<String>
}
fn main() {
    let json_str = r#"

    {
        "names": ["James", "Carl", "Megan"]
    }   

    "#;

    let res = serde_json::from_str(json_str); // res is Result

    if res.is_ok()
    {
        let p: JData = res.unwrap();

        println!("{}", p.names[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        eprintln!("Sorry, couldn't parse JSON :(");
    }

}
```

However, if I change the line `names: Vec<String>` to `names: Vec<u8>` it fails with this error:

> Sorry, couldn't parse JSON :(

Understandbly, this program should fail. But I don't understand why it reaches this line since this error is displayed as a result of `let res = serde_json::from_str(json_str);` which has nothing to do with the `let p: JData = res.unwrap();` step of the program. In other words, the `from_str()` line has no dependency on the subsequent try to parse into JData struct line, yet the error indicates that the `from_str()` line failed, not that it could not parse into `JData`.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `res` is determined by the `let p: JData` at compile time, even if control never reaches that line at runtime. That type, `Result<JData, …>`, controls the behavior of `serde_json::from_str`, which causes it to fail at reading string literals in to `u8`s.